# How to compare these objects in Python

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, printing

```
import urllib2

page =urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = str(page.read())

data2 = str(page.read())

if data == data2: 
    print "yes"
```

Given the above code written in Python I can't figure out why the compare between data and data2

```
if data == data2: 
    print "yes"
```

evaluates as 'not equal' and doesn't print "yes". If some Python experts can help me out understand I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison is done considering `data` and `data2` as objects.

Try this:

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = raw_input(page.read())
data2 = raw_input(page.read())
if data == data2:
    print "yes"
```

I feed the variables `read()` using `raw_input()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution to my own problem. In case anyone else has a similar issue I will explain a bit about what I learned.

Object in python when created have an associated memory location. When you normally assign objects (str is an object), only the memory location is assigned and there is no copy or deep copy of value of the copied object.

There exists a API in Python called 'copy'. So the code will work if I do:

```
import urllib2
import copy

page =urllib2.urlopen(url)

data1 = str(page.read())

data2 = copy.deepcopy(data1)

if data1 == data2: 
    print "yes"
```

Thanks the people who answered. Kind regards